# filters effect on search results in solr

Tags: indexing, solr, query-analyzer

when i query for "elegant" in solr i get results for "elegance" too.

I used these filters for index analyze

```
WhitespaceTokenizerFactory
StopFilterFactory
WordDelimiterFilterFactory
LowerCaseFilterFactory
SynonymFilterFactory
EnglishPorterFilterFactory
RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory
ReversedWildcardFilterFactory
```

and for query analyze:

```
WhitespaceTokenizerFactory
SynonymFilterFactory
StopFilterFactory
WordDelimiterFilterFactory
LowerCaseFilterFactory
EnglishPorterFilterFactory
RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory
```

I want to know which filter affecting my search result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EnglishPorterFilterFactory**

Thats the short answer ;)

A little more information:

English Porter means the english porter stemmer stemming alogrithm. And both elegant and elegance have according to the stemmer (which is a heuristical word root builder) the same stem.

You can verify this online e.g. [Here](http://qaa.ath.cx/porter_js_demo.htmld). Basically you will see "eleg *ant* " and "eleg *ance*" stemmed to the same stem > **eleg**.

From Solr source:

```
       public void inform(ResourceLoader loader) {
            String wordFiles = args.get(PROTECTED_TOKENS);
            if (wordFiles != null) {
                try {
```

Here exactly comes the protwords file into play:

```
                    File protectedWordFiles = new File(wordFiles);
                    if (protectedWordFiles.exists()) {
                        List<String> wlist = loader.getLines(wordFiles);
                        //This cast is safe in Lucene
                        protectedWords = new CharArraySet(wlist, false);//No need to go through StopFilter as before, since it just uses a List internally
                    } else {
                        List<String> files = StrUtils
                                .splitFileNames(wordFiles);
                        for (String file : files) {
                            List<String> wlist = loader.getLines(file
                                    .trim());
                            if (protectedWords == null)
                                protectedWords = new CharArraySet(wlist,
                                        false);
                            else
                                protectedWords.addAll(wlist);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        }
```

Thats the part which affects the stemming. There you see the invocation of the snowball library

```
        public EnglishPorterFilter create(TokenStream input) {
            return new EnglishPorterFilter(input, protectedWords);
        }

    }

    /**
     * English Porter2 filter that doesn't use reflection to
     * adapt lucene to the snowball stemmer code.
     */
    @Deprecated
    class EnglishPorterFilter extends SnowballPorterFilter {
        public EnglishPorterFilter(TokenStream source,
                CharArraySet protWords) {
            super (source, new org.tartarus.snowball.ext.EnglishStemmer(),
                    protWords);
        }
    }
```

Comment: @fyr: Ya i useed solr adimn page to see the effect :), But englishPorterFilter using portwords.txt, in which i included nothing. then how it is doing it ?

Comment: what is the use of portwords.txt

Comment: no it uses only portwords for stems which you fix. It is heuristical so it will make mistakes. The English Porter algorithm uses the snowball library.

Comment: i used it as : <filter class="solr.EnglishPorterFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/> then what is portwords.txt here

Comment: look at my edit. prot words are words which are not stemmed. "protected words"

Comment: U mean, words of which i do not want to stem should include in protwords.txt file

Comment: @fyr let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/955/discussion-between-romi-and-fyr)